# how can we intigrate paypal payment in html side to not use views.py

Tags: python, jquery, django

My checkout page involves integrating PayPal, and we have added jQuery to incorporate the PayPal receiver email. All of this is applied using jQuery. If the payment is successful, we want to redirect to the 'verify_placeorder' page. I need information on how to achieve this because the code provided on the PayPal official website is incorrect, and we're encountering errors when using it.

My checkout page involves integrating PayPal, and we have added jQuery to incorporate the PayPal receiver email. All of this is applied using jQuery. If the payment is successful, we want to redirect to the 'verify_placeorder' page. I need information on how to achieve this because the code provided on the PayPal official website is incorrect, and we're encountering errors when using it

Comment: If you're encountering errors, post those error. If you have code that fails, post that code.